# ios facebook login permission user_... does not working

Tags: ios, facebook, button, authentication, permissions

Hey guys i have problem with facebook login for my ios app.

here is my .m file 
i initilize a login button but this button is asking for just public_profile, email and friends so this button is now working for user_location or user_likes. Why can it be?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Create and customize facebook button
    self.facebookButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_location"];

}
```

it is my .h file for the button defination

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *facebookButton;

@end
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/

Comment: Are you testing with a person that have a role on the app or someone that doesn't have a role on the app? If the person doesn't have a role on the app Facebook needs to review your app before you can ask them for those permissions

Comment: i have created an account with fake information to test app. So this account has no role on the app. but i have already done with review settings. "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" this setting is on at facebook.

Comment: @user3594351 i think you dont need of answer..